# log4net writes to wrong logfile after external dll call

Tags: c#, logging, dll, log4net

strange problem i have here.

So this application is writing all their log files to a directory called Log1 and there in the main.log file.

Now if a call is made to an external dll.
We know that this dll uses log4net as well to write to another logfile.
It writes to the Log2 directory and to the file second.log

But now the strange think happens.
After the first write to second.log all further log messages from our main application are written to this second.log file.

In the main application App.config there is the following settings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="logDirectory" value="Log1" />
    <add key="logFileName" value="main" />
    <add key="logFileExtension" value="log" />
    <add key="logFilesToArchive" value="10" />
    <add key="personalizationDirectory" value="Personalization" />
    <add key="useMockService" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
</appSettings>


  <log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %logger (Line %line) - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

This external dll has the following configurations for log4net:

```
  <appender name="OutputDebugStringAppender" type="log4net.Appender.OutputDebugStringAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>

  <logger name="NamespaceXYZ.Test">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="OutputDebugStringAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </logger>
```

Why does this happen?

Your input is appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but the log4net configurations that you included in your post seem incomplete.  Specifically, the "external dll" configuration refers to "RollingLogFileAppender", but does not have any configuratino for RollingLogFileAppender.  It only shows configuration for OutputDebugStringAppender and ConsoleAppender.  Furthermore, this doesn't answer your question, but I wonder why you don't configure everything to log to the same file anyway?  It seems like it would be easier to debug that way.

Comment: Also, if you look at this link from here on SO, you will see that, generally, a second log4net config file in an application (which, presumably, would include config files read by external dlls) will override the settings from the main application's log4net config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is certainly happening is that the library you are calling triggers a reconfiguration on the [main log4net repository](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/repositories.html). This configuration may be loaded from another configuration file than the one you defined, or programmatically.

You have some options:

- if you have the code for the assembly, use the `RepositoryAttribute` to specify a custom repository for all loggers in the assembly. This way your configuration can live alongside the assembly configuration
- if you cannot change the assembly, use a different repository on *your* code in order to let both logging configurations live side by side. This may force you to rewrite all your logger repositories calls to specify the named repository.
- make a dummy call to the assembly before configuring your loggers; this way you can overwrite the assembly's configuration